# Watir/Page Object Existence Methods Timing Out

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, page-object-gem

I recently upgraded from:

- Page Object 1.2.2
- Watir-Webdriver 0.9.9
- Selenium WebDriver 2.53.0
- Firefox 45.8.0

To:

- Page Object 2.2.0
- Watir 6.3.0
- Selenium-Webdriver 3.4.3
- Firefox 52.2.0

After a little bit of pain, I've finally gotten my tests to start running! One small snag though. The methods `#present?`, `#exists?`, and `#visible?` don't return anything, they just timeout instead. Similarly, `#wait_until`, `x_element.when_present?`, and similar methods all hit the same problem!

Here is my page object:

```
class LoginPage < TeamConnectPage

  MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS = 3

  button :ok, value: /^OK$/i
  button :submit, value: 'Login'
  button :new_session, value: 'New Session'
  link :logout, id: 'LINK_default_logout'
  span :error_message, class: 'texterror'
  text_field :username, name: 'j_username'
  text_field :password, name: 'j_password'

  def login_as(username)
    username = username.to_s
    do_logout if logged_in?
    attempts = 0
    try_login(username)
    while username_element.present?
      fail "#{MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS} logins attempted unsuccessfully for user #{username}" if (attempts+=1) == MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS
      try_login(username)
    end
    if new_session_element.present?
      new_session
      logout_element.when_present(10)
    end
  end

  private

  def try_login(username)
    self.username = username
    self.password = 'test'
    submit
    wait_for_login_submit
  end

  def wait_for_login_submit
    wait_until(10) { !username_element.present? || (username_element.present? && username_element.value.empty?) }
    wait_until(10) { error_message_element.present? || logout_element.present? || new_session_element.present? }
  end

  def do_logout
    logout
  end

  def logged_in?
    logout_element.present?
  end
end
```

Here's the step definition where I'm calling the page object:

```
def login_role role
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(accept_insecure_certs: true)
  @browser ||= Watir::Browser.new(:firefox, desired_capabilities: caps)
  @browser.driver.manage.window.maximize
  @browser.goto('http://ntdmatters-it4.nwie.net/TeamConnect/login')
  @logged_in_user = User[RoleMapping[role]]
  on_page(LoginPage).login_as(@logged_in_user.userid)
end
```

Here's my load order:

```
require 'pry'
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext'
require 'chronic'
require 'page-object'
require 'rspec'
require 'watir'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

```
      timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::Anchor: located: false; {
:id=>"LINK_default_logout", :tag_name=>"a"}> to be located (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
      (eval):1:in `process_watir_call'
      ./features/support/env.src/pages/login_page.rb:48:in `do_logout'
      ./features/support/env.src/pages/login_page.rb:15:in `login_as'
      ./features/step_definitions/login_steps.rb:24:in `login_role'
      ./features/step_definitions/login_steps.rb:2:in `/^I login to Project
with role (.*)$/'
```

What happens is that the script will hit that the `#logged_in?` method and just sit there. Then it will time out and give me the above error message.

I can't help and wonder if this is some sort of configuration problem and that things just need to be loaded correctly or if there's some sort of deeper trap I have fallen into.

EDIT:

When I changed the Selenium logger level to 'Info', I got the following repeated for 30 seconds:

```
2017-07-12 12:11:21 INFO Selenium    >>> http://127.0.0.1:4444/session/8d74a28f-
d8fc-4db6-a851-4f238edf7d70/element | {"using":"css selector","value":"#LINK_def
ault_logout"}
2017-07-12 12:11:21 INFO Selenium <- {"value":{"error":"no such element","messag
e":"Unable to locate element: #LINK_default_logout","stacktrace":"stack backtrac
e:\n   0:           0x4bd56f - <no info>\n   1:           0x4bdcc9 - <no info>\n
   2:           0x43dc4d - <no info>\n   3:           0x44db84 - <no info>\n   4
:           0x44a1ca - <no info>\n   5:           0x4207bc - <no info>\n   6:
        0x405e47 - <no info>\n   7:           0x6db3d9 - <no info>\n   8:
    0x417847 - <no info>\n   9:           0x6d56d3 - <no info>\n  10:         0x
776c59cd - BaseThreadInitThunk"}}
```

EDIT2: This occurs whether or not the element is actually present or not.

Comment: How watir automatically waits for things was the big update from watir-webdriver to watir 6. Run your code with this: `Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :info` and it will show you what calls the driver is seeing. That error means that the element isn't there, but that element isn't getting called in the `#logged_in?` code you showed.

Comment: Given the exception, I would expect the script to be failing on the first line of the `#try_login` method.

Comment: I  pasted the wrong error into the code. I'll edit it, but here's the actual error: `timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for #<Watir::Anchor: located: false; {:id=>"LINK_default_logout", :tag_name=>"a"}> to be located (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)`. I also added the stracktrace into the post as well.

Comment: I added information about what I found from the logger into my post.